# How can I disable the synchronization button in the cmscockpit for the cockpit users?

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, java-ee-6

I want to deactivate the global synchronization of the catalog in the cmscockpit.

Is it possible to do it with usergroups? If yes, how can I do it?

If not, how should I do it?

[image]

Comment: I believe that if the cmscockpit users do not have read access on the SyncJob they should not be able to perform the sync. Have you tried that ?

Comment: But if you want to restrict only one instance( i.e the Global Sync Job) and allow the cmscockpit users to perform other sync jobs(i.e non global) then User Rights is not the answer. This instead can be achieved via a search restriction which will be applied to cmscockpit usergroup and will imply that the Global Sync job only will not be visible to them

Comment: @dj_frunza Search restriction might not be correct, if the User also needs to see the catalog. What they might want is to see both the Source and Target catalog, but to disable the sync.

Comment: @geffchang The way the users are seeing catalogs will not change, They will still be able to see the Source and Target catalogs. The restriction will be applied for "CatalogVersionSyncJob" type meaning that only the global sync job (which I expect to be of this type) will not be visble, hence the sync will not be possible. I did something similar and it worked as expected in backoffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the catalog section selected renderer. I captured the right-click event. I have restricted the display of the button only for the new group that I have created.

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing, disable the synchronization of full catalog for some users, but let them synchronize the pages or components one by one. If I use SearchRestriction on CatalogVersionSyncJob, all synchronization buttons disappear. Please can you explain your solution with Restriction on the button ? Thank you.